# Question about conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $y_a(t):U \to \mathcal{C}$ be any comformal mappitn taking $U \in  \mathcal{C}$ (simply conected domeain ) into a unit disc $D$ and the a point $a\in U$ into its center, $y_a(a)=0$.

Now define a relative diameter of a compact set $K$ with respect to set $U$ as 
\begin{align}
R(U,K)= \max_{a,t \in K} |y_a(t)|.
\end{align}

**My question:**  Let $U$ be a disc of radius $R$ centered at the orign and $K$  a disc of radius $r$ centered at the origin where $r<R$.  What is the value of $R(U,K)$?

I think $R(U,K)$ is equal to $ \frac{2 r}{R}$. However, I am not sure how to start this problem. Specifically, I am not sure how to characterize the mapping $y_a(t)$.

**Edit:**  I would also be happy with an upper bound on $R(U,K)$.

Comment: Where you wrote $\frac{2R}r$, did you mean $\frac{2r}R$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass  Yes, this is what I had in mind. I have corrected this now.  Do you have a way of showing this?

Comment: Do you know of the Riemann mapping theorem and Dirichlet problem (particularly the Poisson kernel)?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri  No I do not, but I would be happy to learn.

Comment: The Riemann mapping theorem is a deep result which states that any two open simply connected proper subsets of $\mathbb C$ are conformally equivalent, and in the 'classical' proof it uses the solution to the Dirichlet problem to 'explicitly' find such an equivalence. The solution to the Dirichlet problem in the unit disk uses the Poisson kernel.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri  Ok. I see. I guess I would have to learn this.   So, do you think that Riemann mapping applies to this problem? Could you give a little description on how if it does ?

Comment: It would provide a way for you to write an expression for $y_a$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri  I see, thanks. Could help me with this part and after that I can finish?

Comment: I munst confess I am not sure this actually leads to a solution, but it does seem worth trying. [This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem#A_sketch_proof) of wikipedia's article on the Riemann mapping theorem should give an idea on how $y_a$ looks like.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Thanks. This might be exactly what I need. I will read up more on this.

Comment: Glad to help! If you do manage to come up with an answer, I'd be interested on reading up on it. =)